# How to use result of SqlDataSource query (specified in aspx file) with ButtonField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, buttonfield, selectcommand

I have specified a `SelectCommand` in `SqlDataSource` (`.aspx` file). This `SelectCommand` query will return data, that will be shown in `GridView`.

Now there is one property named `id` (Primary Key) in select command, whose data will NOT be shown on `GridView`, rather I want to send this 'id' to another page when the respective `ButtonField` is clicked.

[image: Grid View Data]

The image above shows `GridView`. Every column represents activity fields while every row represents a unique activity. The last column has `ButtonFields` for registering for an activity.

I want to send students to *Register For Activity* Page along with 'id' of the row clicked. Mind you, value of 'id' is not shown on `GridView`.

Kindly suggest me a good way to achieve it.

I think one solution could be: Accessing the value of 'id' in backend (.cs) file and then sending id's value through ButtonField Command. but I am not sure if it can be accessed in .cs file?

**ASPX code:**

```html
<asp:GridView ID="ShowActivitiesGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="location" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date_of_activity" HeaderText="Date of Activity" SortExpression="date_of_activity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="organization" HeaderText="Organization" SortExpression="organization" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="no_of_student" HeaderText="No of Student" SortExpression="no_of_student" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" />
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="RowCommand" HeaderText="Register For Activity" ShowHeader="True" Text="Register" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [name], [location], [date_of_activity], [organization], [no_of_student], [description] FROM [Activities]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace ButtonField for ItemTemplate on the `aspx`

```
    <asp:GridView ID="ShowActivitiesGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="location" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="date_of_activity" HeaderText="Date of Activity" SortExpression="date_of_activity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="organization" HeaderText="Organization" SortExpression="organization" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="no_of_student" HeaderText="No of Student" SortExpression="no_of_student" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="description" />
                <asp:ButtonField CommandName="RowCommand" HeaderText="Register For Activity" ShowHeader="True" Text="Register" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove" ShowHeader="False">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegisterActivity" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Register For Activity" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' oncommand="btnRegisterActivity_Command" />
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [name], [location], [date_of_activity], [organization], [no_of_student], [description] FROM [Activities]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

on the page `cs` file

```
        protected void btnRegisterActivity_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int myId = (int)e.CommandArgument;

            //Do whatever you want
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a little correction, `eval("id")` generates an error which can be corrected by replacing small 'e' with capital 'E'. So, `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'`.